# How to check response from $httpProvider.interceptors responseError?

Tags: angularjs

in AngularJs 1.2.x,  [the docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$http) only provide a rejection object,  how can we see the actual response object?  (to see things like http status code)

**edit**: here's an example from the docs:

```
// register the interceptor via an anonymous factory
$httpProvider.interceptors.push(function($q, dependency1, dependency2) {
  return {
    'responseError': function(rejection) {
      // do something on error
      if (canRecover(rejection)) {
        return responseOrNewPromise
      }
      return $q.reject(rejection);
    };
});
```

that example shows some unknown rejection object (no docs on what it's members are).  the old (deprecated responseInterceptors allow query of the response object. (check for status=401, for example)   how are you supposed to query for 401 service errors with the new interceptor functionality?

Comment: Can you add snippet of code\content that you are referring to?

Comment: okie, sorry i wasn't super clear.  i tried to add more details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i am coding my usage of this to the point of being able to run it,

and so i set a breakpoint, and see that the "rejection" object has a .status property.

if a server doesn't exist, it will == 0
otherwise, it seems to return the http status code.   (i see 404 so far)

I havent coded a real service point so i'll update this answer and/or accept it once i get that done.

**update:**  yes,  the .status field returns the http response status, and 0 if server not found.  so this is the valid answer!

Comment: I get a wrong status: -1 instead of 403, what the server returns... any ideas?